# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout wrong content size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

For given layout, UICollectionView always returns content size which is equal to UICollectionView size, even if items go beyond the UICollectionView.

```swift
private lazy var layout: UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout = {
    let margin = 8.0
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
        heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)
    )
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .estimated(56),
        heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)
    )
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: .zero, leading: margin, bottom: .zero, trailing: margin)
    section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
}()
```

Also I suspect, because of that I cannot programatically scroll to items beyond the screen.
What can be wrong here?

I tried to change widthDimension of item and the group, contentInsets, but it didn't work.

**UPDATE**

The correct way to to this was to use:

```swift
NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 1)
```

and

```swift
section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuousGroupLeadingBoundary
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the size of the group.

Instead of this:

```
 let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
    widthDimension: .estimated(56),
    heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)
)
```

Try:

```
let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
    widthDimension: .estimated(56),
    heightDimension: .estimated(200)
)
```

I think the problem is that you didn't set the height for the group.

Comment: It didn't work also, issue still occurs. Moreover my UICollectionView has fixed height,  so the group height is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

`section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .paging`

Comment: It didn't work, issue still occurs.